# Is there any way to create a LXDE customized panel as a launcher?

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, lxpanel

I am currently using (and enjoying) Lubuntu 12.10 on an older desktop, since the last time I tested it, it has improved a lot, but I really got used to Unity workflow and it has become quite an habit to manage applications and windows with the launcher.

Using Synapse as an attempt to replace dash, I already created a panel on the left margin of the desktop with the shortcuts to my favorite programs, but they only open the apps, the window management is still made on the bottom panel. I tried to use this default bottom panel on the left but the results were not satisfatory. Besides, some applications still make use of tray icons on the bottom panel, like Dropbox.

I dont really mind if I have to keep using the tray icons, I can just autohide the panel and reveal it when I need it, my main concern is to manage opened windows on the left customized panel instead of the default one.

Here it is a screenshot to help me clarify what I am trying to do.
http://imm.io/NUqT

Comment: Try using a dock like docky, awn, cairo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest running Cairo because it had the most configurations available. I run Lubuntu 12.10 with xcompmgrm manager enabled and have no issues with work-flow. I can run multi panels and choose which lunchers I want.

Easy to install just open synaptic and choose cairo-dock. It will supply the correct dependencies and you are off and running.

Comment: Even though I would like to make use of LXDE panels instead of using another utility, Cairo dock really provides a decent and light docking experience, after some configuration. If anyone still has an idea on how to do this with LXPanels, post it here, but Cairo does enough me so far.

Answer (score 0):

go to panel preferences in lxpanel, panel applets tab, and load an application launch bar plugin instance. Now your LXDE panel is custmized as a launcher, and you can configure that plugin entry to include whatever apps you want.

Comment: just gathered that you are most concerned with managing open windows in your lxpanel on the side. simply follow my instructions presented above but instead of adding an application launch bar plugin entry, youll use the desktop pager plugin taskbar(window manager) entry. now you can enjoy both application launchers and opened windows on the same leftside panel and get rid of your bottom one.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you [edit] your answer and incorporate your comment into the answer?  Please? ;-)